# Controlling the Order of Execution in Rails Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, order-of-execution

New to Ruby and programming in general. So far I've had no problems finding answers to any questions I've had, but can't find this one.

In my app the Teams controller new and create actions are creating several new records across several associated models. One of those records is failing to create because it appears the lower record `@pool_user` is being executed before `@department` and thus `@department.id` is nil and email cannot be null.

To test, I removed the `@pool_user` line and inserted a specific value into `:userid =>` under `@competence` and it executed in the expected order, creating all records as expected.

I am using Devise for the User model, which I suspect may be influencing it initializing first, but I can't seem to find a way to get them to execute in the correct order.

### teams_controller.rb

```
def new
  @team = Team.new
  @department = Department.new
  @competence = Competence.new
  @pool_user = User.new
  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @team }
  end
end

def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  @department = @team.departments.build(:organization_id => User.current.organization_id, :team_id => @team.id)
  @pool_user = @team.users.build(:email => @department.id).save(:validate => false)
  @competence = @team.competences.build(:team_id => @team.id, :user_id => @pool_user.id)


  respond_to do |format|
    if @team.save
      format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @team, status: :created, location: @team }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Feel free to correct any other bad practices or general noob moves you see here. I just want to figure out why it isn't building in the correct order. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me the association between these models? so that can workout something so that every thing works as expected.

Comment: @SagarBommidi - aren't the relationships obvious from the code above?

Comment: that's quite obvious.

Comment: while building @pool_user, why you are assigning department id to email, is that a typo?

Comment: not a typo, mostly just a bad idea. that will be an invisible user that will be used behind the scenes for pooling logic and I wanted a simple way to identify those users. everyone else requires proper email formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calling a build on collection will not actually save the record. You need to save it before using id attribute.

after executing,

```
@team = Team.new(params[:team])
```

or

```
@department = @team.departments.build(:organization_id => User.current.organization_id, :team_id => @team.id)
```

@team.id  or  @department.id will give you the nil value.

As well

```
@team.users.build(:email => @department.id).save(:validate => false)
```

will return Boolean value i.e. true or false.

After building you should save this values explicit if you want, like

```
    @team = Team.new(params[:team])
    @team.save
```

and

```
    @pool_user = @team.users.build(:email => @department.id)
    @pool_user.save(:validate => false)
```

should work.

I suggest you to try this all in rails console before actually writing any code.

Comment: As well, as suggested by Mischa, no need to pass explicit attribute (team_id) in build method  **@team.departments.build**.

Comment: One more thing, if you want to skip validation, you need to use save(:validate => false). You can not achieve this with create method.

Comment: That was the problem. I do need to bypass validation on user, so I went with your solution. Thank you greatly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the order of execution. The problem is that [`.build`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection-build) creates an object in memory, but doesn't save it to the database yet. That's why you don't have an `id` yet. You may want to use [`.create`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection-create) instead.

Another problem with your code is that you are passing `:team_id => @team.id` when it's not necessary.

In this code:

```
@team.departments.build
```

`:team_id` will be set implicitly by the `build` method. So, you can simply do:

```
@department = @team.departments.build(:organization_id => ...)
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'll make those changes and let you know what I get. Thanks.